# InvalidOperationException: Objects is currently used elsewhere!

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I get that mistake.. I use a loop to run through a bunch of images to be drawn..I also use multithreading..

What could cause that problem and how could it be prevented?

I use winforms

Additional information:

it tells me if i use graphics after GetHDv method, call the ReleaseHDC method..

What does it mean?

section of the code:

A thread created like this:

Before I did this:
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

Now I am testing with this:

Backgroundworker back=new backgroundworker();
back.runworkerAsync();

is that the root of the exception?

Comment: In general, UI objects can't be used other than on the thread that created them. That *may* be the problem, but it's hard to tell without seeing any code. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: could you post a stack trace? (your exception should contain one) but if you ask for a guess: you are using a non-threadsafe resource in more than one thread at the same time... possible solution: remove the concurrent access situation

Comment: hmmm. I use a backgroundworker that i added to the winform.. other than that i havent got another thread  that i added to the winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/01/28/quot-object-is-currently-in-use-elsewhere-quot-error.aspx)

> What's really happening with "Object is currently in use elsewhere" is
>   that GDI+ is complaining that the device context (DC) that it is
>   trying to use is already "in use".  With WinForms, this generally
>   means there is a recursive Graphics.GetHdc occurring.  GetHdc must
>   match a ReleaseHdc before any other GetHdc.

And

> You can encounter this exception if you're drawing to a form from
>   multiple threads.  You'll likely also be encountering a
>   cross-threading exception as well.  The solution in this case is to
>   not use multiple threads when accessing a form, including drawing.

Comment: How do i use multiple threads..?

Comment: I have a background worker (called: Backgroundworker1, which i use constantly,,) if i use one programmatically..will it solve the problem ( a new background worker will be created each time )